# Dataflow BigQuery input - parallel processing semantics/performance?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Dataflow starts reading Bigquery export results in parallel with the export job.

What is the semantic of the parallel read operation? Should I expect a difference in performance between parallel read operation, and read operation *once* a BQ export job (in my case ~10TB) is done? Is it possible to force Dataflow service to wait for the BQ export to finish, and only then start processing the data?

Comment: I nominate for reopen because this question is about programming against Cloud Dataflow (performance expectations of a certain programming pattern), rather than about general software/hardware usage. To the topic: from point of view of Dataflow, waiting for the full export job to finish would be strictly worse. Export job produces files which Dataflow reads, and there's no performance benefit in waiting for more files to appear before starting to read files that already appeared.

Comment: this question looks to me specific enough to be alive. voting for reopenning